# Calculating T-Test within Large Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, scipy

The below code runs a t-statistic within a large dataframe (`rnadf`) based on masked values from another dataframe (`cnvdf_maked`).  Before, I was putting my results into a dictionary and turning it into a pandas dataframe.  These dataframes became too large for my memory, so I had to switch to writing the results to a file line by line, as below on the last line.

The above code takes a little less than a week to produce one complete file.  I have many dataframes to run this on, as in many pairs of the DFs `rnadf` and `cnvdf`.  I have 138 pairs of these DFs pickled in a directory, so I was making my script "parallel" by running each DF pair's ttest caluclation at once in its own `screen` session -- for a total of 138 screen sessions.  This was a clunky way to do it.  When result files get to be around 2.6Gb, they fail with an `OS Error 30`.

I've since moved to a new server with about 1Tb of memory, so I'm no longer practically constrained by memory.  I'm open to doing two things to improve optimization: ***1) make each calculated ttest faster***, and ***2) parallelize this process to run on many different dataframes at once*** without using separate screen sessions.

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

# sample dataframes
rnadf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
cnvdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 25)), columns=list('BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY5'))
cnvdf_mask = cnvdf <= 500

inter = list(set(cnvdf_mask.columns).intersection(rnadf.columns))
cnvdf_mask, rnadf = cnvdf_mask[inter], rnadf[inter]

with open('out_tab.txt', 'w') as f:
    for pr in itertools.product(rnadf.index, cnvdf_mask.index):
        rnaPos = np.array(rnadf.loc[pr[0]][cnvdf_mask.loc[pr[1]]].dropna())
        rnaNeg = np.array(rnadf.loc[pr[0]][~cnvdf_mask.loc[pr[1]]].dropna())
        t, p = stats.ttest_ind(rnaPos, rnaNeg)
        f.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(t, p, pr))  # changed pr table to tuple of str indices joined by '&'
```

Comment: The full text of `OS Error 30` gives it away: `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system`. This shouldn't have any relation to the size of the file, except you're on a server. Your server likely puts a limit on the max size of the `/tmp` folder per user. Possibly you're running over the limit of your `/tmp` folder and you didn't have write permissions on whatever comes after that.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. make each calculated ttest faster

[cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
indicates that `ttest()` dominates the running time.
(Thank you for a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), BTW!)

I don't see any mathematical tricks that would let us do
fewer tests because some of them are identical.
Adjusting the `permutations=` parameter produced
no useful effects. So tl;dr: "no".

> 2. parallelize this process to run on many different dataframes at once

That's straightforward, given that memory now is no object.
Your code already has nice looping structure due to `itertools.product()`.

The standard solution uses
[`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)
module.
We'll need a slightly different loop structure.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ttest(rna_pos, rna_neg, pr):
    t, p = stats.ttest_ind(rna_pos, rna_neg)
    return '{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(t, p, pr)

work = [(np.array(rnadf.loc[pr[0]][cnvdf_mask.loc[pr[1]]].dropna()),
         np.array(rnadf.loc[pr[0]][~cnvdf_mask.loc[pr[1]]].dropna()),
         str(pr),
        )
    for pr in itertools.product(rnadf.index, cnvdf_mask.index)
]

with open('out_tab.txt', 'w') as f:
    with Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.starmap(ttest, work):
            f.write(result)
```

This will try to burn all cores.
Each has its own interpreter, its own
[GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).
It's worth noting that cost to serialize / deserialize
args + results should be much less than cost of running `ttest()`.
Delaying big `import`s until you're down in the
child process can also be helpful.

If you want to use the CPUs of several hosts,
then [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html)
or [Vaex](https://vaex.io)
are happy to help.

Comment: I'll note that a _minimal example_ (your link) is a [so] thing - for review, code must be __complete__ rather than minimal, and should be __real__ rather than an example.  But yes, runnable code makes for better reviews.